# Discord Code - Sending random images from folder

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I have a very simple and short Code. It works, kind of. It doesn't really randomly send Images, just 2 of them over and over again. Maybe you can help me out a bit.

```
 if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "aot")) {
    number = 14;
    imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number = 1 + 1)) + 1;
    message.channel.send ({files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".png"]})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns you're assigning `1+1` to your `number` variable at `(number = 1 + 1)`. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but assuming you have 14 images and they were named starting at 1, here's the solution:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "aot")) {
    number = 14;
    imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * number) + 1;
    message.channel.send ({files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".png"]})
}
```